# Does setuptools download the latest available dependency versions from pypi?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm setting up the [mozmill-automation](https://github.com/mozilla/mozmill-automation) package by running:

`python setup.py develop`

The setup.py file has a dependency definition:

```
deps = [...,
        'mozmill == 2.1-dev',
        'mozversion >= 0.7'
        ]

...

setup(..., install_requires=deps, ...)
```

It ends up downloading *mozversion 1.1*, which is the latest available version on pypi. Is setuptools guaranteed to download the latest available dependency versions?

It appears so, as per https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html (search for "latest available version" on that page). But, I'm not sure if setuptools uses easy_install to download dependencies.

Note: I'm not using virtualenv